# Arguments are same for angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following directive:

```
app.directive('filterComponent', function() {  
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'filter-component.html',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        console.log(attrs);
        scope.type =  attrs["type"];
    }
  };
});
```

and i call it three times in different places in my html:

```
<filter-component type="TYPE1"></filter-component>
<filter-component type="TYPE2"></filter-component>
<filter-component type="TYPE3"></filter-component>
```

and this is directive's html:

```
<div id="{{type}}" class="filter-container">
    <div layout="row" class="rhs-text" ng-show="!noTargetSelectedYet">
        <md-input-container flex="">
             <label>Search</label>
             <input style="position: relative; top: 7.8px;" ng-model="filterText">
         </md-input-container> 
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that their `id` (thus, `{{type}}`) become the same (the last one, `TYPE3`) although i send different values for type (also seen in `console.log(attrs)`).

What is wrong with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set isolated scope for your directive so it does not affect the outer scope:

```
app.directive('filterComponent', function() {  
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        type: '='
    },
    templateUrl: 'filter-component.html',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        console.log(attrs);
        scope.type =  attrs["type"];
    }
  };
});
```

> Best Practice: Use the scope option to create isolate scopes when
>   making components that you want to reuse throughout your app.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

**Update**

To also use `filterText`:

```
app.directive('filterComponent', function() {  
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        type: '@', // You want this to be passed as a string
        filterText: '=' // You want this to be passed as reference
    },
    templateUrl: 'filter-component.html',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        console.log(attrs);
        scope.type =  attrs["type"];
    }
  };
});
```

HTML:

```
<filter-component type="TYPE1" filterText="filterText"></filter-component>
```

You can refer to this for a better understanding on isolate scopes: http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-custom-angularjs-directives-part-2-isolate-scope

Comment: but i need scope in order to use other variables in my controller. is it possible?

Comment: well, if you want to change the value of the outer scope variable, it will be set to the last one. and you also don't need this `scope.type =  attrs["type"];`; and do you need the values from the controller scope or need to modify them? if you need the values why not just pass them to the directive?

Comment: for example `filterText` that i use in directive's html. I tried it with your solution and `filterText` could not be reached. Objects are passed stringified and are not referred to the original scope variable.

Comment: for your updated solution, i take `function (locals) {              return parentGet(scope, locals);            }` for `filterText` in directive's html. Is & a special character or just to initialize the variable?

Comment: @Asqan sorry, my bad. it should be `=`

Comment: It is working. However, i had to change `filterText` attribute in html, in directive's scope definition and directive's html to just another name for name conflicts. Thank you !